# Why does React / NextJS still render the return if there is an IF to route?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a web app in NextJS.  I have some logic that will check if a user is logged in, else route to the login page.

But in reality this code actually returns an error where the `userContext` cannot be defined.  That's why I have a check for a user first.

I hypothesis the `return` statement is being run despite the verification for existing user.  Is this true of React?

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'displayName')
```

Full-ish code:

```js
... some imports and stuff

export default function Account(pageProps) {
  const route = useRouter()
  const userContext = useUserContext()

  if (!userContext) {
    route.push("/login")
  } 

  return (
      <Box sx={{ mt: "3rem" }}>
        {user &&
          <Typography variant="h2">
            Welcome{userContext.displayName && ' ' + userContext.displayName}!
          </Typography>
        }
      </Box>
  )
```

NOTE: I resolved this issue by adding a `return` statement in the IF statement.  But I still would like to know why this happens.

Comment: `userContext` might be giving an `{}` so `if` statement won't execute and you can't access any fields from an `{}`. Check by consoling the value of `userContext`

Answer (score 0):

try this function to determine whether object or anything is empty or not :

```
// custom function to check if an object / array or some variable is empty
export const isEmpty = ( value ) =>
  value === undefined ||
  value === null ||
  ( typeof value === "object" && Object.keys( value ).length === 0 ) ||
  ( typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0 );
```

Then use it as following :

```
  if (userContext && isEmpty(userContext)) {
    return route.push("/login");
  }
....
```